# How to add a Jbutton in a JPanel on a project built with Netbeans GUI editor?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am using NetBeans IDE to build my GUI on which I would like to insert a Button (jButtonMy) in the jPanel1 when I click on the jButton1. I create the button (jButtonMy) in the callback associated with the  jButton that is available, but nothing is displayed in the Jpanel1.

Netbeans generates verbose code I copy/past below

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 243, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 168, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(161, 161, 161)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(91, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 53, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       jButtonMy = new javax.swing.JButton();
       jButtonMy.setText("jButtonMy");
       jButtonMy.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
       jPanel1.add(jButtonMy);
       jPanel1.revalidate();
       jPanel1.repaint();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

   private javax.swing.JButton jButtonMy;

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"insert a Button (jButtonMy) in the jPanel1 when I click on the jButton1"* I'd recommend a different approach. Add all buttons when the GUI is first being made, but **enable** the second button when the first is activated.

Answer (score -1):

It is better when you don't forget the setBounds, otherwise you are creating a very very tiny button.
Correct code is therefore

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       jButtonMy = new javax.swing.JButton();
       jButtonMy.setText("jButtonMy");
       jPanel1.add(jButtonMy);
       jButtonMy.setVisible(true);
       jButtonMy.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
       jPanel1.repaint();
       jPanel1.revalidate();
    }
```

Comment: The real problem is that you are using a GroupLayout and you haven't set up any constraints when you add the button to the panel. You should NOT be using setBounds(). So the better solution is to NOT use the IDE to generate your code. Then you can be in full control of the layout manager used by your project.